# Javascript Object Generator Function

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in Javascript to generate an object , for example

```
function newObject(name,value) {
   // Some Awesome Logic
   return theObject
}
var test = newObject('mike',32);
```

And The return from new object to be an object

```
console.log(test); // returns an object

{
  "mike": 32
}
```

I need a function like this to be reusable... HELP PLEASE

Comment: That is what constructors are for.

Comment: might be just me but doesn't the constructor already create a new object each time you invoke it (reuseable)?

Comment: Given the suggestive name of the function, that seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: i have been trying for hours, does anyone has a code example my brain is fried..

Comment: `const newObject = (k, v) => ({[k]: v});` But it's not obvious how this is better than simply using the object literal in-place.

Answer (score 3):

Use the constructor pattern, with the `new` keyword, and the property name can be defined with `[ ]`:

```js
function myObject(name,value) {
   this[name] = value;
}
var test = new myObject('mike',32);
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function newObject(name, value) {
   var theObject = {};      // the plain object
   theObject[name] = value; // assign the value under the key name (read about bracket notation)
   return theObject;        // return the object
}

var test = newObject('mike', 32);

console.log(test);
```

In recent ECMAScript version you can do it in one line like this:

```js
function newObject(name, value) {
  return { [name]: value }; // the key will be the value of name not "name"
}

var test = newObject('mike', 32);

console.log(test);
```